# Additional JavaScript tags in next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I very recently started programming with react & next.js (previously I was using node.js)
and I made my first application, but on inspecting the page I saw a lot of additional JavaScript (image given below)

here's my directory:

[image]

here's my index.js source code:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      hello world
      </div>
  )
}
```

Here's what I mean by additional JavaScript

[image]

Since I've been using node.js I'm not very familiar with all this JavaScript being placed in the code automatically,
could someone please explain what all of this is, where it's coming from and why it's necessary?

Comment: A JavaScript bundler is doing this, this lets you only load necessary code instead of loading all 40MB of JavaScript at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

next.js or react.js are libraries to create single page applications, you don't need to write html manually now, everything will be generated using javscript. these files are just internal library script files generated by webpack tool in chunks, you might be thinking, why is it so, like we can also store these all scripts into one file, but actually webpack breaks modules into chunks, so that it will only load these files whenever needed for optimization of web performace.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough yet to understand everything you just said, but as far as I understood you're saying that instead of loading every page individually (with traditional html and javascript) only 1 page is being sent with all the components and to increase the efficiency of the components the "additional javascript" is being written which I am seeing upon inspecting, correct?

Comment: yes, additional javascript is a code from framework and modern development tools, which helps you to build single page applications. and you are in a development mode, when you will build the project, you will only get two files index.html and script.js(minified and combined). there are also lot of options in webpack config, to break code in chunks, i.e script.js will be splitted in chunks. hope this answers your question. if you wanna learn more about it, check **Virtual Dom Concept**, and read some thing about **webpack**.